# MySQL Average Excluding some NULL Values

Tags: mysql

Can't seem to figure this out for the life of me although  the logic is quite simple.

I have a small MySQL database that contains the following fields:

- variety
- picked
- weight

I have setup a view in MySQL to report out what the average weight of each variety is using SUM(weight)/SUM(picked) BUT.... sometimes the weight is not input, therefore I'd like to exclude the sum of picked in the average as to not give a false average.

I was using:

```
SELECT variety, if(weight="", sum(weight)/sum(picked),0) As AvgWeight
FROM `harvest`
GROUP BY variety
```

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

```
| picked| weight|
| :---: |  :---:|
|    10 |    20 |
|    10 |    30 |
|    10 |       |
```

I would want the above to result in AvgWeight as 2.0 and not 1.6666667

Comment: select (sum ../ sum ..)  ... where weight != ''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume that you want the average as 2.5, not 2.0.  If so, calculate the average using conditional aggregations:

```
select variety,
       (sum(case when weight > 0 then weight else 0 end) /
        sum(case when weight > 0 then picked else 0 end)
       ) as average
from harvest
group by variety;
```

The expression `weight > 0` will eliminate both `NULL` values and blank values (although if `weight` is defined as a numeric type, the value cannot be blank).

Comment: Yes I meant 2.5 and wrote the wrong value, perfectly what I was looking for thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

do a `coalesce(weight, 0)`

This will return the first non-null integer for your comparison and will return the row as part of the count without messing with your final aggregations.